# Verification: anybody seen apache2 respond with two responses and a header inside?

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I already filed a bug report on both launchpad.net and BugZilla, but I wanted to verify if someone else has experienced this problem. We use apache2 as a reverse proxy server for a client's website. Sometimes, random, but in 2% of all requests, we get instead of the normal response content,  a sort of double response: response A, then the header for response B, then response B. It is quite annoying, because the website is very important to the client and a non-functional website might scare users away.

If we access the web server directly, i.e. without the proxy server, there are no problems at all.

I could repeat the whole story here (and I will do so when requested), but I hope a link to the bug report will suffice: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1874932

The original question on StackOverflow, when I thought it was a programming issue on the web server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304769/xpages-server-sends-wrong-data-apache2-problem

Again, my question: is anyone familiar with this phenomenon, and if so, is there a quick fix? Or should we go for a different reverse proxy server??

Thanks for your help!

***UPDATE***

Part of the error.log file, for the page that refreshes once per minute. The first 2 paragraphs are correct, the 3rd resulted in an error, the 4th is correct again. Hope this gives you some clues...

```
[Sun Apr 26 12:09:22.769237 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2797:tid 139815423543040] [client 12.34.56.789:40606] AH01964: Connection to child 64 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:09:23.012497 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2797:tid 139815278311168] [client 12.34.56.789:40608] AH01964: Connection to child 73 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:09:23.552035 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815423543040] mod_proxy.c(1161): [client 12.34.56.789:40606] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:09:23.552080 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815423543040] proxy_util.c(2210): [client 12.34.56.789:40606] AH00944: connecting http://www.website.com:81/database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:09:23.552090 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815423543040] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 12.34.56.789:40606] AH00947: connected /database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__

[Sun Apr 26 12:10:22.701472 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2796:tid 139815202776832] [client 12.34.56.789:40616] AH01964: Connection to child 18 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:10:22.953876 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2796:tid 139815320274688] [client 12.34.56.789:40624] AH01964: Connection to child 4 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:10:23.442074 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815202776832] mod_proxy.c(1161): [client 12.34.56.789:40616] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:10:23.442138 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815202776832] proxy_util.c(2210): [client 12.34.56.789:40616] AH00944: connecting http://www.website.com:81/database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:10:23.442153 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815202776832] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 12.34.56.789:40616] AH00947: connected /database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__

[Sun Apr 26 12:11:21.443567 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2796:tid 139815244740352] [client 12.34.56.789:40644] AH01964: Connection to child 13 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:11:21.534754 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815244740352] mod_proxy.c(1161): [client 12.34.56.789:40644] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:11:21.534798 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815244740352] proxy_util.c(2210): [client 12.34.56.789:40644] AH00944: connecting http://www.website.com:81/database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:11:21.534804 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815244740352] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 12.34.56.789:40644] AH00947: connected /database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:12:22.627945 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2797:tid 139815219562240] [client 12.34.56.789:40658] AH01964: Connection to child 80 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:12:22.872992 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2797:tid 139815227954944] [client 12.34.56.789:40660] AH01964: Connection to child 79 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:12:23.303433 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815219562240] mod_proxy.c(1161): [client 12.34.56.789:40658] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:12:23.303488 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815219562240] proxy_util.c(2210): [client 12.34.56.789:40658] AH00944: connecting http://www.website.com:81/database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:12:23.303496 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2797:tid 139815219562240] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 12.34.56.789:40658] AH00947: connected /database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__

[Sun Apr 26 12:13:21.524116 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2796:tid 139815286703872] [client 12.34.56.789:40672] AH01964: Connection to child 8 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:13:21.817112 2020] [ssl:info] [pid 2796:tid 139815345452800] [client 12.34.56.789:40674] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server www.website.com:443)
[Sun Apr 26 12:13:22.121726 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815286703872] mod_proxy.c(1161): [client 12.34.56.789:40672] AH01143: Running scheme http handler (attempt 0), referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:13:22.121779 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815286703872] proxy_util.c(2210): [client 12.34.56.789:40672] AH00944: connecting http://www.website.com:81/database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
[Sun Apr 26 12:13:22.121785 2020] [proxy:debug] [pid 2796:tid 139815286703872] proxy_util.c(2419): [client 12.34.56.789:40672] AH00947: connected /database.nsf/Page.xsp/Page?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3A_id2%3A_id3%3A_id47%3A_id48%3A0%3A_id49%3A_id51%3AtblMemory&$$viewid=!3fa81zwu176jh8r7dcutv7eff! to www.website.com:81, referer: https://www.website.com/__Test__
```

Comment: Without a replicateable setup, it'll be near impossible to debug this.  I have seen this type of behavior in rare cases when the reverse proxy server is caching content to be served, but without knowing your configuration I can't actually comment on that.  (I usually disable caching on the reverse proxy so it never caches the data and passes the data directly without caching)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that first thing tomorrow.

Comment: I checked, but caching isn't enabled. Only socache_shmcb_module is loaded.

Comment: Log extract added.

Comment: Correction: it's not 2% but in the order of 10% of the requests that fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that this problem is 'solved' now, for we prepared a switch to nginx... we encountered some problems, but not the overrun problem as discussed above. The bug is still there, in Apache, of course.